# sitting or standing during kiddush or havdalah

Tags: kiddush

1. Where in *halacha* is it mentioned that when anyone else is listening to someone make *kiddush* or *havdalah*, *l’chatchilah* they must be either sitting or standing depending on what the person is doing?
2. In addition, the *Chazon Ish* indicated that if a person did not do so he/ she is not yotzei even b’di’eved. Can you please tell me the source for this?